# Updating Old Data in CRM

Tags: crm, custom-attributes, account, lead

I made a field named "Lead Type" in Lead Form.I also created a new field named "Account Type" in Account form. I create a new mapping between these two fields ie. when the value of "Lead Type" field is filled in the lead form and when we qualify this lead into Account, This value is automatically filled in the "Account Type" field.This whole process is running well with no problem. Now the problem is that I have some Accounts in my CRM without having the value of  "Account Type" Field, I want this data  to be automatically updated or with any process but not manually. Will it be possible in CRM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of the above question. I made a workflow for Accounts which will update all the existing records. In workflow, I make a condition that when the status of the record changes, update the records.

So to update the records, first I will Inactive all the Accounts and when I Activate it again, all the records are updated and the value of the new field will also be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is the export all the leads and accounts without a lead type to Excel, give them all a lead type, then reimport.

**Edit**

If you have to update millions of records, it will probably be easiest to write a little console application that finds those records without types and sets the type.

Or you could try an existing product like [Scribe](http://www.scribesoft.com/).

Or as an alternative you could set the type on demand, e.g. only when you need the type do you set it.

Comment: I want some better solution because I have millions of records and It is not feasible to manually edit all the records.
Thnaks anyways for the answer.

Comment: You probably should have put that in the question then.